# A simple number theoretical question

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

$x$ and $d$ are natural numbers, they satisfy the relation

$$x = \frac{781 + 256 (3d-1)}{81} $$

I can see $d=26$ and $x=253$ could be one pair of possible solutions. However, is this unique? If not, can one tell me what are the other solutions for $d$ and $x$?

Answer (score 2):

This is a line with a rational slope, namely $256/27$ (on the $dx$-plane). Hence there are an infinite number of solutions $(d,x)$ of the form

$$(26 + 27t, 253 + 256t),$$

for integers $t$. See if you can prove why.

Comment: Thank you dear. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to obtain all solutions with congruences:

This relation means that
\begin{align}
781 + 256 (3d-1)\bmod 81&\iff 52+ 13(3d-1)\equiv 0
\iff39(1+d)\equiv 0 \bmod 81\\
\scriptstyle\text{(simplifying by }3)&\iff 13(1+d)\equiv 0 \bmod 27\\
\scriptstyle (13\text{ is a unit }\bmod 27) &\iff d\equiv -1 \bmod 27.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$x = \frac{781 + 256 (3d-1)}{81}$ means that $x = \frac{781 + 256 (3d-1)}{81}$ is an integer and that $81$ divides into $781+256(3d-1)$ evenly.

$\frac {781 + 256(3d-1)}{81}= \frac {525 + 768 d}{81} = \frac {175 + 256d}{27}$ so $27$ divides into $175 + 256d$ evenly.

$175+256d = 27*(6 + 9d) + (13+13d)$ so $27$ must divide into $13+13d$ evenly.

As $13$ and $27$ are relatively prime $27$ must divide into $1+d$ evenly.

So there must be an integer $m$ so that $1+d = 27m$ or $d = 27m-1$.

So we can have $d= 26, 53, 80, ..... $

So long as $d=27m -1$ then

$x = \frac {781+256(3(27m-1)-1)}{81}= \frac{525+768(27m-1)}{81}=\frac {27*768m-243}{81}= 256m- 3$

.... if you are comfortably with modular arithmetic:

$x=\frac{781 + 256 (3d-1)}{81}$ being an integer means

$781+256(3d-1) \equiv 0 \pmod {81}$

$256*3d \equiv -525 \pmod {81}$

$39d \equiv -39\pmod{81}$

$d\equiv -1 \pmod {\frac{81}{\gcd(39,81}}$

$d \equiv -1 \pmod{27}$

would be easier. (we only have to do remaiders... and etc...)